# PECS does not work on return types with interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, pecs

Consider the following example,

```
class ClsA {}
class ClsB {}

interface IntA {}
interface IntB {}
```

And I have 2 very similar methods:

```
static <T extends ClsA> T returnC() { // Here T extends the class
    return null;
}

static <T extends IntA> T returnI() { // Here T extends the interface
    return null;
}
```

And then the method calls:

```
ClsA ac = returnC(); // This works fine based on inference.

IntA ai = returnI(); // Similarly this works fine based on inference.
```

But consider the below 2:

```
ClsB bc = returnC(); // ERROR as expected.
```

**Eclipse Error:**

> Bound mismatch: The generic method returnC() of type Testing is not applicable for the arguments (). The inferred type ClsB&ClsA is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends ClsA>`

But the following code compiles fine:

```
IntB bi = returnI(); // Works fine
```

**Why is that for interface, the generics bound is not considered in return types?**

Comment: Confirmed with javac, too. Both JDK7u40 and JDK8u20.

Comment: PECS has nothing to do with the question, actually :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic words here are ***raws*** and ***multiple inheritance***.

Lets first take a look on your `returnC` method:

```
static <T extends ClsA> T returnC() {
    return null;
}
```

The type `T` is bounded with `ClsA`, which means that if you invoke the **raw** `returnC` method, then the return type will be simply `ClsA`.

True, when you have this statement: `ClsA ac = returnC();` the compiler succeeds with the compilation, because the **raw** return type of the method is `ClsA`, which is compatible with the type of `ac`.

The the raw return type is also the reason for which the statement `ClsB bc = returnC();` does not compile.

---

Now let's take a look on the `returnI` method:

```
static <T extends IntA> T returnI() { // Here T extends the interface
    return null;
}
```

Here, the type parameter is bound to `IntA` only.

This, however, doesn't mean that the replacement type for `T` must implement only `IntA` - the type **can** implement `IntA` and `IntB` at the same time. Statements like `IntB bi = returnI();` are allowed, because a type can implement multiple interfaces, but cannot implement multiple classes.

Consider this class:

```
class SomethingReallyCool implements IntA, IntB { }
```

This type is a **valid** substitute for the type-parameter of `returnI()` and the proof for that is this statement:

```
IntB bi = YourClass.<SomethingReallyCool>returnI();
```

Why? Because it's a class that implements `IntA` and this is the only thing the compiler cares about.